# binding data to parent node in D3 instead of selection -- pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, d3.js

What is the recommended pattern in D3 when abstracting "components"?

Let's say I have a list. Normally I would do

```
d3.select('ol')
  .selectAll('li')
  .data(array)
  .enter()
  .append('li')
  .text(_.property('label'))
```

However, when abstracting this out into a component, at the place of use I would like to just do

```
d3.select('ol')
  .data(array)
  .call(component)
```

The problem is that the data needs to be bound to the `.selectAll`, so people would need to do the `.selectAll` at the place of use, but that breaches the abstraction (people would need to know what type of element this component will be appending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting proposal.
I implemented 'component' like this and checked it working.
(The source is modified a little bit for my test.)
I want to know the solution withount using  `__data__`...

```
var array = [
    {label: 'label1'},
    {label: 'label2'},
    {label: 'label3'},
    {label: 'label4'},
    {label: 'label5'}
]

function component(selection) {
    selection.selectAll('li')
        .data(selection.datum()) // edited to use .datum() instead of selection[0][0].__data__
        .enter()
        .append('li')
        .text(_.property('label'))
}

d3.select('ol')
    .datum(array)
    .call(component)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know D3 set the `.call()`ed function's `this` to the selection. Anyway I think `selection.datum()` would return the data, I will try that. But if not, this version will work

Comment: Thank you Peter for modifying my code. This must be a correct answer.